# Tech says furnace has no ground

Tags: furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I hooked up an Ecobee 3 thermostat that has worked great the last couple years.  This weekend my furnace went out.

I had a tech came out and he got it going again but told me it would work better with the old Honeywell thermostat and not the smart one because my furnace doesn't have a ground.

I'm confused because the board has a C terminal and I hooked a blue wire to it and to the C connection on my thermostat.

What in the world is he talking about?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this question to the tech.  If the furnace has a "C" terminal I can't imagine why he'd say there isn't one.

Comment: Unless the furnace is more than 60 years old it would be odd for it not to have ground, but the ground might be broken/disconnected.  Ground is a safety and usually is there to protect you, not make a device work.  The tech's wording might not have been the best.

Comment: You might revise to make your question more appropriate to a DIY site, where you're trying to solve the problem yourself. We can't tell you what some other person thinks. Provide information about your hardware and symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

With a mutli-meter you can check the voltage on the lines. There should be 24V AC between R and C.

If C is not reading 24V AC, it may be failing, missing or disconnected, and you should then check and measure 24V AC between R and W or R and G. This would confirm that the R is supplying correctly, and that thus the fault lies with the C.

Make sure your multi meter is in AC mode, and that you have it set to the range that is just above 24V, so 50V or 30V or whatever the knobs/settings provide. Some multimeters do this automatically.

If C - R is not reading 24AC at the thermostat, repeat at the furnace terminal.

The wording "doesn't have a ground" is rather ambiguous. If your furnace is not properly grounded ("bonded") to earth, that's an electrical wiring problem that must be fixed immediately. It's a safety issue. But likely this is not what was meant. Often "ground" in low voltage systems such as the thermostat can also refer to the "common" or 0V wire, which together with R is part of the power/voltage supply. Older thermostats could be smart too if they had batteries They could replace the "dumb" mercury switch without new wiring because they didn't need the furnace's power supply to run their clock and remember programs, so there was no need for the "C". Now the "C" is used to help power the thermostat with the "R", and reduce battery replacement.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They said *ground* (line voltage) not *common* (low voltage). The last furnace I put in said :

"Unit will not operate correctly unless properly *grounded*."

He's taking about you hiring an electrician to bring it up to code, so as to stop using the case of some flexible as a ground return path, or even worse, the nothing it has because it's run in plastic with two wires.

Modern thermostats do not like using the case of the machine (ground) as the common (... use the C terminal). And modern units don't like being un-grounded.